# (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'admin'@'SERVER-CONNECTION' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to a mySQL database on AWS using SQLAlchemy but I keep getting this error. My permissions and inbound rules for the RDS is definitely correct and so is the login details.

```
import sqlalchemy as sqla
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import traceback
import glob
import os
from pprint import pprint
import simplejson as json
import requests
import time
from IPython.display import display

URI = "URI"
PORT="3306"
DB="DB"
USER="admin"
PASSWORD="PASSWORD"


engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://{}:{}:@{}:{}/{}".format(USER, PASSWORD, URI, PORT, DB), echo=True)


sql = """
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS demodublinbikes3;
""" 

engine.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Yeah it just comes up "%" as a host

Comment: You have an extra `:` before the `@`.